# Add breadcrumb naviagation on custom master page

Tags: custom-masterpage, breadcrumb

I have a custom master page applied to a SharePoint site. However, I want to add a breadcrumb to it.

I have been reading about how SharePoint 2013 has breadcrumb already but its hidden by default in Seattle master page. Could it be enabled in a custom master page?  It would be a good practice to make use of existing SharePoint controls instead of creating new ones from scratch.

These are my findings so far, however not sure which to implement on a custom master page.
http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/ 
http://blog.amtopm.be/2013/01/04/sp2013-adding-breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link you shared is for getting back the fly-out navigation menu which was available in SharePoint 2010, but it was made hidden in SharePoint 2013.

If you are trying to get that control back on your custom masterpage, you should copy the code snippet given of first [link](http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/) in your custom masterpage. If you will change in Seattle master page, it will reflected in each of the sub site as well. So according to me use your custom master page and place the custom snippet in it.

If you are planning to have a horizontal breadcrumb in SharePoint 2013 using Design Manager, you can refer this [link](http://pradiprathod.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/add-breadcrumb-with-sharepoint-2013-design-manager/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have used the link you provided. It works just fine. However, it shows "Site collection" as the root. Any idea how to remove it?

Comment: Yes, you can do some scripting to hide the root node using jQuery.

Comment: Oh well, I was thinking of that but I thought there might another way of doing it in the masterpage code. 
Anyway, Thanks so much!!